# using sample() or an equivalent on 2 variables of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large dataset, a subset of which looks like this:

```
Var1    Var2
9     29_13x
14    41y
9     51_13x
4     101_13x
14    105y
14    109y
9     113_13x
9     114_13x
14    116y
14    123y
4     124_13x
14    124y
14    126y
4     134_13x
4     135_13x
4     137_13x
9     138_13x
4     139_13x
14    140y
9     142_13x
4     143_13x
```

My code sits inside a loop and I would like to be able to sample without replacement, a certain number of Var2 (defined by the loop iteration) from each of the different Var1 categories. So for i=4 I'd like to get something like this:

```
29_13x
51_13x
113_13x
138_13x
```

which are all from Var1=9

```
41y
109y
126y
140y
```

from Var1=14, and

```
101_13x
134_13x
137_13x
139_13x
```

all from Var1=4.

I can't get `sample()` to work across more than one variable and can't find any other way to do this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options.

Using `sample` with `by` or `tapply`:

```
by(mydf$Var2, mydf$Var1, FUN=function(x) sample(x, 4))
tapply(mydf$Var2, mydf$Var1, FUN=function(x) sample(x, 4))
```

Here's some example output with `tapply`:

```
out <- tapply(mydf$Var2, mydf$Var1, FUN=function(x) sample(x, 4))
out
# $`4`
# [1] "101_13x" "143_13x" "124_13x" "134_13x"
# 
# $`9`
# [1] "114_13x" "113_13x" "142_13x" "29_13x" 
# 
# $`14`
# [1] "116y" "109y" "140y" "105y"
```

You can also extract individual vectors by index position or by name:

```
out[[3]]
# [1] "116y" "126y" "124y" "105y"

out[["14"]]
# [1] "116y" "126y" "124y" "105y"
```

Subsetting based on a random variable `rank`ed by a grouping variable:

```
x <- rnorm(nrow(mydf))
mydf[ave(x, mydf$Var1, FUN = rank) %in% 1:4, ]
```

Comment: many thanks for these, they are great, but i have one other question, the output of both of these makes it difficult (for me at least) to extract just the Var2s that were subsetted. Is it easy enough to get a vector of all these, regardless of which Var1 they came from (which at this point in the process is redundant)?

Comment: @user3122022, the `tapply` variant is perhaps the easiest one to use. You'll get a `list` of vectors as the result. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks, but my problem is, inside the loop there will be different numbers of Var1 and Var2, so I need a generic statement that will give me all the Var2 as one vector (or better still single column dataframe). So for the above example I need `101_13x,143_13x,124_13x,134_13x,114_13x,113_13x,142_13x,29_13x,116y,109y,140y,105y` as a vector and nothing else attached.

Comment: @user3122022, so just use `unlist`.